# How to get user friendly values for trigonometric functions?

Tags: java, android, trigonometry, calculator

I am developing an android app. for mathematical calculations. There I have some buttons like sin,cos,tan which should show their respective trigonometric values, for that I am using corresponding methods of java.lang.Math class and that works fine. But after some tests I came to know that, it shows some results as follows

```
sin(90)=0.89399........   //I want it to show 1
cos(90)=-0.44807........  //I want it to show 0
tan(90)=-1.995200......   //I want it to show Infinity as sin(90)/cos(90)=1/0=Infinity
```

Like the above examples there are many which show results like this. What should I do this for getting the results as mentioned above. Please help me.

Comment: I guess the problem is that java.lang.math works with rad instead of degrees?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that java uses radians and [not degrees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#cos%28double%29). You have to convert the angle to rad first.

```
Double rad = degrees /180 * pi;
```

Answer (score 4):

First, trigonometric functions do not work with degrees that you are using. You have to send 3.1415926/2 instead of 90. In this case `sin` will be much closer to 1 and cos much closer to 0.

But the numbers will still be floating point. If you want to round them for presentation use `DecimalFormat` class or `String.format()` method.

Answer (score 3):

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sin%28double%29) to the rescue:

> Parameters:
>        a - an angle, in **radians**.

(emphasis mine)

Convert your degrees into radians first. 360 degrees = 2 * pi.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Math.round()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28float%29).

Also, last time I checked, whenever you devide by 0 you do not get infinity. Division by 0 is undefined.

Also, Java uses radians for trigonometric functions, so be sure you are using radians and not degrees or gradians.